# Потоки и возможные проблемы с ними

Tags: многопоточность, файлы, потоки-данных, qt, c++

Предположим у нас есть заранее открытый файл. Дескриптор этого файла передается в разные потоки. В этих потоках происходит с него чтения (только чтения).

Возникает вполне логическая проблема по перемещению по файлу. Один поток прочитал файл и позиция для чтения стала в конце. Другой поток должен переместить позицию для чтения на начало и опять прочитать. Так продолжается постоянно. Не спрашивайте, почему читать постоянно один файл, это просто пример, чтобы упростить вопрос.

И так теперь собственно основная проблема:

Пусть 1-ый поток читает файл, еще до окончания чтения запустился 2-ой поток и он переместил позицию в файле на начало. Тогда 1-ый поток читает опять с начала?! Так не должно быть. Вообщем так может дойти до того, что один с потоков постоянно будет читать один файл и никогда не прочитает его полностью, а другие потоки будут получать не правильные (урезаныe) части файла. Я прав?

Как этого избежать? Использовать блокировку? Но очень важна скорость.

Число потоков колебаться в районе 20. Чтения с файла происходит сразу одним куском через метод readAll(). Файл должен быть прочитать отдельно n-ое число раз. Кешировать в памяти его содержимое не можно.

Как быть? Идеи?

Спасибо.

Comment: А что мешает открыть файл в неэксклюзивном режиме в каждом потоке, а не расшаривать его между потоками? Несинхронизированный доступ к структуре данных из разных потоков — это, как известно, undefined behaviour.

Comment: @err: В упор не вижу, каким образом это мешает. Объясните.

Comment: @err: Зачем так, сделайте проще. В каждом потоке, если вам нужен файл, откройте его заново, поработайте с ним и закройте.

Или поместите объект, представляющий собой файл, в thread local storage, и в следующий раз не переоткрывайте, а возьмите оттуда. (Ну и закройте при уничтожении потока или окончании обработки.)

Или заведите `map<thread_id, FILE*>`. Да как угодно можно.

Comment: @err: Стоп. Что-то не так с вашей архитектурой. **Почему** вам нужно одновременное чтение тысячи файлов в разных потоках? Вы что-то делаете не так.

Comment: @err: Тогда не морочьте голову и используйте `map<thread_id, FILE*>`. Не забудьте операции с `map` делать под блокировкой. Если тот, кто ставил задание, будет возражать, ответьте ему, что он клинический идиот, а затраты на блокировку пренебрежимо малы по сравнению с файловыми операциями.

Comment: @err: Вот этого, простите, не знаю. Есть у `QThread` что-то наподобие `ID`? Если нету, придётся использовать системно-зависимые штуки, например, [WinAPI/`GetCurrentThreadId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683183%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Или если у вас C++11, покатит стандартный [`this_thread::get_id()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/get_id).

Comment: @err: А писать вам придётся: в начале-то `map` пустой.

---
Внутренний `map` можно не блокировать, всё равно доступ к нему только из одного потока. Кстати, наверное лучше `map<thread_id, map<string, FILE*>*>`? Не уверен, не получите ли вы случайно копию при сигнатуре без указателя.

Comment: @VladD... нфайлы откроются и мап сформируется до запуска потоков... тоесть блокировка не нужна.
Да я использую С++11, но мне не удается получить id, т.к использую не стандартные средства с++, а qt с++ (а именно QThreadPool)

Comment: @err: По идее, `this_thread::get_id()` должен работать в любом случае, т. к. даёт системно-зависимый id потока. Попробуйте, уверен, что сработает.

---
Только узнать заранее ID потока у вас не выйдет. Так что назначать внутренний `map` потоку придётся динамически. Пичалька.

Comment: Прошу прощения, что вмешиваюсь) Маленькая ремарка: в Qt чтобы узнать id потока можно воспользоваться статической функцией `Qt::HANDLE QThread::currentThreadId()`)

Comment: Вот я вижу в вопросе такие требования:

     Чтения с файла происходит сразу одним куском через метод readAll(). Файл должен быть прочитать отдельно n-ое число раз. Кешировать в памяти его содержимое не можно.

Следует ли из этого, что каждый поток несколько раз (через определенное время) перечитает весь файл в свой локальный буфер (так сказать, делает snapshot)?

Думаю, что на самом деле, оптимальным решением будет открывать файл в потоке (**open()!!!**) и читать его *одним syscall read()*.

И все это (c `map<FILE *>` тоже) будет работать для 20 потоков, тоько если файл не очень большой.

Comment: @avp размер файла может быть до 1 мб (иногда больше). Открывать файл нужно, скорее всего, до запуска потоков, т.к перед эти я написал, что каждый поток открывает файл, но медленно работало. Если открыть n-файлов в потоке, то QTHREADPOOL через определенное время закроет их, удалив неиспользуемые потоки. После чтения файла, пусть, для примера, его содержимое отправиться по почте и все, но файл может быть отправлен еще раз через промежуток времени. В памяти держать содержимое многих файлов не очень хочется. А почему придуманное решения будет работать только для 20 потоков, если файл не большой?

Comment: @err, 1 Mbyte -- это не очень большой файл. Так что в этом плане не волнуйтесь.

Наверное я не понял Вашу задачу и поэтому предложил другое решение, основанное на том, что вообще не нужно держать открытый файл, который одновременно читают несколько потоков. Собственно, именно об этой проблеме (как я понял) Вы и рассказываете в своем вопросе.


Если изложите проблему в целом (можно вообще не привлекать концепцию потоков, как необходимый элемент ее решения), то можно попробовать спроектировать ее реализацию.

Желательно также знать, в какой ОС и каком окружении Вы это делаете.

Comment: @avp передача файлов клиенту по его запросу. клиент дает запрос на файл и он пересылается. Без потоков здесь, точно не обойтись - клиентов много, часто что-то запрашиваю. Приложение кроссплатформенное. qt c++. Вроде бы написал уже решения, какое было предложено ранее через map<string, FILE*> Но возникла пробела: вдруг файл будет удален сторонним приложением, а мы его должны причитать + он еще открыт в нашей программе. Что тогда? Как отследить?

Comment: Очередной файловый суперсервер (и обязательно кроссплатформенный) :-}.

@err, универсальные вещи почти никогда не попадают в категорию **супер**.

Для начала попробуйте сделать *очень просто*. На каждый connect создавайте поток, который открывает файл, поблочно читает-передает  в цикле  и затем завершается (не забудьте прочесть подтверждение от клиента о конце передачи). 

Никаких пулов потоков. Никакого самостоятельного кэширования файлов (на самом деле ОС  сделает это не хуже Вас).

Сделаете, проведите нагрузочное тестирование. И только после этого стоит рассматривать более сложные схемы.

Comment: @avp я сначала написал как вы кажете: файл каждый раз открывается, но работает медленно. Если 1 раз открыть, то в 3-4 раза быстрее происходит обработка. Почему никак пулов?

Comment: @err, никаких пулов -- сначала для простоты программы.

--

Вообще-то, в Linux я бы делал detached pthreads и в них использовал системный вызов sendfile (man 2 sendfile) для передачи самого тела файла. Т.е. переложил бы всю эту кухню с синхронизацией и эффективным разделением ресурсов на ядро (а для чего еще его люди писали?).

Но, понятно, это не кроссплатформенно.

--

А разговоры быстрее-медленнее имеют смысл при описании методики замеров и конкретных цифр.

Вот как именно (и в какой сетевой конфигурации) Вы все измеряли, что получили разницу в 3-4 раза?

--

Oops, последний комментарий...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Суммируя дискуссию в комментариях: решением должно быть открыть файл неэксклюзивно в каждом потоке. Для этого в каждом потоке нужно поддерживать структуру `map<string, FILE*>`.

Чтобы иметь такую структуру на каждый поток, можно положить указатель на неё в thread local storage. Если он недоступен, можно организовать ещё один, глобальный `map<thread_id, map<string, FILE*>*>`.

Для того, чтобы узнать `thread_id`, проще всего воспользоваться функцией [`this_thread::get_id()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/get_id), доступной в C++11.

Однако, следите, чтобы не выйти за ограничение по количеству открытых файлов на процесс.

Удачи вам!